# Zoom doesn't work when directions are set google maps v3

Tags: maps, zooming, directions

Hope someone can help me with this, im trying to show two direction points with zoom and centered so i can just show the 2 points instead of all the map! it seems that the zoom doesn't work.

here is my code

```
       var map;
        function initialize(){                  
                  var mapOptions = {
                  zoom: 14,
                  disableDefaultUI: true,
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };

                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);


                var request = {
                        origin:"Mexico",
                        destination:"Montreal",
                        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
                };

                var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
                var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

                // Indicamos dónde esta el mapa para renderizarnos
                directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

                directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                      directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
                    }
                  }); 
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To fix your problem change:

```
disableDefaultUI: true,
```

to

```
disableDefaultUI: false,
```

From the [Google Maps API]: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#DisablingDefaults

> You may instead wish to turn off the API's default UI settings. To do
>   so, set the Map's disableDefaultUI property (within the Map options
>   object) to true. **This property disables any automatic UI behavior from
>   the Google Maps API.**

If you still want to disable UI elements, you should probably do them individually.